# JavaScript variables to PHP in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I've read several forums according to this subject and none of the things I've tried worked.

My problem is the post from AJAX in JavaScript to a PHP page it doesn't work when I make and echo of the variable its empty don't know why. What I'm trying to do is this: I have an API that sends me a JSON. I build an HTML code with that code, and everything is working with that. I'm building this table:

[image: Example of table]

When I hit the delete button it shows this:

[image: Delete button]

And the result is that I get redirected to the page anularfunc.php

HTML code of main page:

```
<?php
//Habilitar las sesiones
$codigoError ="";
session_start();

//Validar si existen las sesiones
if(!isset($_SESSION['vsJsonAgencias']))
{
    header("location:../index.php");
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['codigoError'])){
$codigoError = $_SESSION['codigoError']; 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="../css/tabla.css" rel="stylesheet">
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="SGLabz">

    <title>CitasWeb</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link href="../css/portfolio-item.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/form-basic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/form.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CitasWeb</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">



      <!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
        <form class="form-basic" id="form-basic" action="http://localhost/citasweb/php/menu.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-title-row">
                <h1>Citas Programadas</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <table id="table_tingkat_jual">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>No. CITA</th>
                      <th>AGENCIA</th>
                      <th>GESTION</th>
                      <th>FECHA</th>
                      <th>GESTOR</th>
                      <th>HORA</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>


                        <?php

                        $jsonData =$_SESSION['jsonHistorial']; 
                        $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);
                        foreach($jsonDataObject->Citas as $option)
                        {
                            echo '<tr >';
                        echo '<td id="'. $option->NoCita . '">'. $option->NoCita . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $option->Agencia . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $option->Gestion . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $option->Fecha . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $option->Gestor . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $option->hora . '</td>';
                        echo '<td><a type="submit" onclick="confirmar();" ><IMG SRC="delete.png" ALT="ELIMINAR" WIDTH=40 HEIGHT=40/></a></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        }

                        ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" >Aceptar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Citas Web 2017</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmar(){
        var mensaje = confirm('¿Está seguro de anular esta cita?');
        if (mensaje) {
            $('#table_tingkat_jual tr').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var $this = $(this);
                var tdid = $this.find('td[id]').attr('id');             
                var json_str = tdid;
                $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "anularfunc.php",
                    data: { "name" : json_str },
                    success: function (data) { alert(data) },
                    eror: function (data) { alert(data) }
                });
    });


                //alert("TD ID " + tdid);
            });

            window.location.href="http://localhost/citasweb/anularfunc.php";
        }
        else{
            window.location.href="http://localhost/citasweb/php/historialCita.php";
        }
    }
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirmar(){
    var mensaje = confirm('¿Está seguro de anular esta cita?');
    if (mensaje) {
        $('#table_tingkat_jual tr').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var $this = $(this);
            var tdid = $this.find('td[id]').attr('id');             
            var json_str = tdid;
            $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "anularfunc.php",
                data: { "name" : json_str },
                success: function (data) { alert(data) },
                eror: function (data) { alert(data) }
            });
});


            //alert("TD ID " + tdid);
        });

        window.location.href="http://localhost/citasweb/anularfunc.php";
    }
    else{
        window.location.href="http://localhost/citasweb/php/historialCita.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

And the final PHP files that receives the post is this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 
$fields_string="";
$jsonAgencias = $_SESSION['vsJsonAgencias'];

echo "HELLO";
  $postData = $_POST['name'];
  echo $postData;
print_r($postData);

?>
```

I placed an echo hello just to make sure it's showing something, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: in you confirmar function .. are you sure you have a proper value for tdid ?.. try  check for the real content

Comment: Yeah i double check the value for tdid i even placed a string manually as the value i send to the php and still empty

Comment: Apparently the ajax is not sending the data to the php.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You need to take a closer look at your code. Your inline onclick handler is setting up a click handler on the tr element (it doesn't actually call the code there). You also immediately change your `location.href` so that immediately starts your page change.

Comment: The onclick handler is on the delete button and it shows the pop up with the "var mensaje = confirm('¿Está seguro de anular esta cita?');" to confirm that selection is about to be deleted and if i print the id from the tr with the value tdid it shows the actual value.

Comment: Im going to try changing deleting the location.href to see if that works

Comment: Yes but you are also setting up a click handler on the tr element, this part: `$('#table_tingkat_jual tr').click(function(e) {` that sets up a click handler, it does not run the code you have inside it at that point

Comment: Can you give me some advice on how to run the code, im new in js ive read  a lot of forums about it and i though that was the best way to do it any advice would be helpfull

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)